# UICollectionView with cells anywhere on the screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview

[image]

Is this possible to make using UICollectionView or some custom subclass? What I want is to be able to move the cells all over the screen, arbitrarily and independently one from another, and it should be possible to make them in different sizes.

Edit: I do also need scrolling and cell reuse.

Comment: UICollectionView is not best fitted for what you're describing (you don't have scrolling, or cell reuse it seems), I think you're better of with creating a custom UIView with drag/layout support.

Comment: Actually, I do need both of these, I edited my question now.

Answer (score -1):

From Documentation

> For custom layouts, you want to subclass UICollectionViewLayout, which
>   provides you with a fresh starting point for your design.

I would suggest you to look into the following

`UICollectionViewLayout`
`UICollectionViewFlowlayout`

Check this one out, for a quick tutorial [Custom layout tutorial](http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial)